# How to make MSM photodetector more selective?

Tags: photodiode

I got a question, how can I make Metal-Semicondutor-Metal photodiode more selective in terms of wavenlength spectrum. I need to mention I cannot use Bragg reflectors like in RCE photodetectors. All I can use is quantum wells and p, n doping layers. To be more precise, I need to narrow the absorption spectrum below 1300 nm, let's say to 1250-1350 nm. In general the upper range (1350 nm) is just limited by bandgap of active material, so that's not a problem for me
[image]

Comment: what's the side from which your diode is illuminated? Contacts-side, or perpendicular? Can you change the geometry of your diode? My guess is that you could at least reduce the quantum efficiency of the frequencies you don't want if you could change dimensions and direction. But: without a detailed description of your whole system: you're really expecting EE.SE to debug your photonic device based on the description that its bandwidth is larger than you want?

Comment: Why can't you use coatings? Can you put a glass window in front of your device with a coating?

Comment: generally "how can I solve {problem} in an extremely complicated and restriction rich environment {technology}" is pretty much impossible to answer without **a lot** of background on **why** {problem} and **which** restrictions apply.

Comment: Well, it's simple MSM 2D strucure like in here https://prnt.sc/i6ejy9. To the best of my knowledge I cannot change the goemetry of my photodiode, the structure is illuminated contacts-side. The materials showed in the picture aren't the ones I use, obviously. Basically, I was told to use quantum wells, but really I don't see how could it work.

Comment: "simple M2M 2D structure" is simply not true. To produce a M2M structure, you'll need some semiconductor fabrication, Metal junction production, bonding process, some way to couple in light, some way to apply potential difference, some way to measure current… non of this is a "there's only one way" thing. So, far, far, far too many unknowns!

Comment: and: prnt.sc links work on exactly none of my devices. Use another image hoster. This site uses imgur.com, usually.

Comment: I found tons of articles on how to do this.  Why can't you see them?

Comment: https://imgur.com/GrzjJTf. I'm just simulating MSM device in crosslight APSYS. I can use optical coating with chosen thickness and refractive index. But would it help to make device more selective?

Comment: example http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1098-2760(19960820)12:6%3C310::AID-MOP2%3E3.0.CO;2-I/full

Comment: Yes, a multilayer coating can be used to make a longpass or bandpass filter. But this would be a form of DBR, which you said you can't use.